# Delay in receiving new message from specific channel in telegram using telethon

Tags: python, telethon

I have my python code to watch in 3 channels in telegram and do something when new message arrives.
My issue is that from one specific channel i receive the new message with a delay of some seconds (15 -60 seconds).

Some info about the channels:

Channel A : 2.4K subscribers

Channel B : 2.2K subscribers

Channel C : 2    subscribers

The delay is in channel B here is my code.

The delay is compared with the timestamp from https://web.telegram.org/

I am using the latest version of telethon

```
  @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=(-100channel_A_id, -100channel_B_id, -100channel_C_id)))
    async def handler(event):
        message = event.raw_text
        logging.warning('Received ' + message)
        sender = await event.get_sender()
        sender_id = str(sender.id)
        channel_name = utils.get_display_name(sender)
        msg = "Channel name: " + channel_name + " | ID: " + sender_id
        logging.warning(msg)
        sender = channels.get(sender_id)
        if sender is A:
            link = get_link(message)
            linkQueue.put(link)
        elif sender is FILIPPINEZOS:
            manage_message(message, B)
        elif sender is IAMGM:
            manage_message(message, C)


    with client:
        # Run the client until Ctrl+C is pressed
        print('(Press Ctrl+C to stop this)')
        client.run_until_disconnected()
```

[photo from https://web.telegram.org/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBRgL.png)

[photo from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoKpZ.png)

Comment: Telegram Web may be using [`updates.getChannelDifference`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/updates/get_channel_difference.html), which could hint Telegram you are interested in the channel (and deliver updates to it faster). Use [`channels.getFullChannel`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/channels/get_full_channel.html) to get the `pts`. I've never had delays or tested this myself though.

Comment: I am also facing same issue even after using updates.getchannelDifference function. If you have found solution this,please reply , it will be helpful for me

Comment: @KrisHJodu i changed the telegram client to https://docs.pyrogram.org/